# Get Comment HTML For Ajax - Wordpress

Tags: html, ajax, wordpress, comments

I've set up an ajax request for submitting a comment (based on tutorials) and I've been able to at least get a comment back in the form of a JSON set of values using `get_comment( $id, $output );`

But even better, I'd like to use the typical HTML template that wordpress uses when outputting the HTML on the page / single template.

**Simply stated, how do get a comment with html, and nothing else?**